Dungeons & Dragons 3: The Book of Vile Darkness - Only NOT.
This evening I watched a film on YouTube called Dungeons & Dragons 3: The Book of Vile Darkness, and although I've never seen that movie before, the plot and characters were instantly recognizable. I'm almost positive I've seen the "same" movie with a different name and different actors. 
A young knight is undergoing his initiation to become a paladin, but is seemingly rejected by his deity. After a pep talk from his paladin father ("You're still a knight!") the group is attacked and all the paladins are killed, except the young knight. 
The knight begins a quest to find the bad guys, and ends up teaming up with traditionally "evil" D&D characters - a necromancer type, an assassin, and a big fellow (maybe a barbarian?) all led by a female elf and bent on pillaging and plundering. 
Because he needs their help, he convinces them that he, too is evil (but he isn't) and all along the way, he has to carefully convince them not to do bad things without being found out. For instance, "Don't kill the survivors - we can take them to the village and they'll think we are heroes and let us in!" which they interpret as "and we can rob them blind!"
There's a scene I remember in which the necromancer-type fellow, who wears a sort of phantom of the opera mask, is "checking out" the dangers in a cave or room or something, and his eye floats down the various corridors, still attached by an ever lengthening optic nerve. Something happens - a trap, perhaps - that severs the nerve and causes him to cry out in pain. 
That's all I can remember from the other film, though there were other scenes in the D&D3 movie that struck me as familiar. 
Does anyone know what the movie I saw originally might have been? I seem to remembering it having significantly higher production values than the one I saw last night. 

But this is pretty much D&D3's plot beat for beat, which would mean that everything was copied from (or by) another movie. While that's not unheard of, are you sure all of these things are in that other movie too? It also featured a druid in a phantom of the opera mask with an extendable eye stalk?

Do you remember any differences?  Maybe you just saw the same movie before with a different name or something. Which of these things you're listing are from BoVD, earlier movie, or both? We're assuming all from both without any further guidance.

Walt - "Beat for beat" is exactly my point! Some houseguests and I have taken to watching a movie late at night.we watched the first two Dungeons & Dragons from DVD's in my collection on successive nights, and we're surprised to discover there was a third D&D movie - one that apparently had been released in the U.K.only (we're in the U.S.). When I found it on YouTube, we watched it, and not 10 minutes into the film, I realized I had seen it before. But not with these actors, and under a different name, and with some minor differences that made the one I had seen better (at least in my mind).

Mxyzplk - I did remember a few differences - or rather, there are some things about the D&D3 movie that I DON'T remember from the one I had seen previously. First, the D&D3 movie has a oddly long intro sequence, with animations and narration providing the background story (which I couldn't understand - the sound effects drowned out the narration in the YouTube video). Secondly, D&D3 has a nude scene or two in a brothel that I don't remember from the one I had seen. And, though both versions could easily be labeled as "cheesy", I  don't remember "my" version being quite so poorly done over all.

According to IMDB this movie was, in fact, released in the US.  Approximately two months after it was released in the UK.  So maybe it was this movie you saw after all.  Given all the very specific similarities and the lack of memorable differences (sorry, but not remembering something being the same is not the same thing as specifically remembering it being different) I would be fairly surprised if there was actually a second - unrelated, no less - movie with all this in common.

Steve-O - You're probably right. I'm of an age where things are more easily forgotten than remembered, but I am typically sharp enough to have at least remembered that a third film existed, had it been shown under the same name. Perhaps I stumbled upon a version edited for television late one night (which would explain the things I don't remember being in "my" version), and perhaps I'm contrasting the relatively poor quality of the YouTube version with the quality of the broadcast version as a difference in production values. Either way, it's not terribly important. Thanks for your reply!

FWIW, it's not uncommon for filmmakers to remake things later. For example, Lena Dunham made Tiny Furniture before making Girls. The first episode of Girls is basically the same plot as Tiny Furniture.
